# Correlation vs measure of independence

Tags: correlation, p-value

So I have some data of which I'm looking at two different metrics, the first being "how sick a person is (higher = sicker)", and the second being "the presence of adverse events", and I've run 20 experiments:

```
table=
  Columns 1 through 11

     1     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     2     0     2
     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     1     0     0

  Columns 12 through 20

     2     1     2     2     2     2     2     0     1
     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0
```

The correlation coefficient between these two data sets is -0.0066, which to me implies there is a fair amount of independence. I guess the question is now, is there any way to expose that certainty.

I understand that the t-statistic can be calculated from that, and equals
-0.0281, which suggests a p-value (dof = 2) of 0.980134 (two-tailed) or 0.490067 (one tailed).

Now I may be stating the obvious, but does the high p-value imply a high probability of independence?

Comment: @NickCox and @PeterFlom Correlation is more then just a measure of linearity, rather I would argue that it assesses a (any?) monotonic relationship. In Peter's example, if `y<- (x+1)^2`, the correlation actually high. Given that I am expecting more adverse events with illness, that would suggest a least a minimal positive value, in this case I see none... I used Pearson's because I was looking at a lot of metrics at once, and this value stood out. Will review the data with the other suggested methods.

Comment: Correlation is a bundle of ideas, not a singl one. If you are interested in measuring (approximation to) monotonicity, you should use a rank correlation measure.

Comment: @NickCox Indeed: [Thirteen Ways to Look at the Correlation Coefficient](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2685263?uid=3739808&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21102313286497)

Comment: That paper was cited by me in http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0041

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the correlation says is that there isn't much correlation between these two variables; that is not exactly the same as independence. It is possible to have completely dependent variables with a 0 correlation:

```
set.seed(201139)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- x^2
cor(x,y) # -.18, with another seed, could be closer to 0
plot(x,y) #perfect dependence
```

I am not sure what t-statistic you are running.

Another point is that your data are all 0, 1 and 2, so you should use rank correlation rather than Pearson; arguably you shouldn't use correlation at all.

A better test of independence for data such as these might be chi-square:

```
x <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1)
y <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
table(x,y)
chisq.test(x,y)
fisher.test(x,y)
```

which, here, also suggests independence (but you don't want to accept the null)

Comment: see comment above, also, my t-statistic is based on an article from the American Statician: "Thirteen Ways to Look at the Correlation Coefficient"

Answer (score 5):

This relatively short question raises numerous different issues. Here are some:

In statistics, independence is an absolute condition, not something that exists in degrees.

Correlation measures correlation, which is at most linear dependence. A zero correlation could reflect some nonlinear relationship.

A check on your data shows that you are using Pearson correlation, which does use the idea of linear dependence.

Correlation may not be the best way to answer your question, depending on what it is, precisely. Some statistical people are happy with trying to measure correlation between an ordinal and a binary variable, which you seem to have here, but for others, that's a real stretch.

Positive alternatives are: a two-way table with some measure of association designed for categorical variables; a spineplot or mosaic plot.

(Incidentally, what is an "experiment" here? Your 20 pairs of values just look like 20 cases or observations, which I would not call separate experiments.)

Comment: We were typing at the same time, with almost the same thoughts. GMTA :-)

Comment: My elementary teachers would always couple "Great minds think alike" with "Fools don't differ" but I prefer your choice.

Comment: @NickCox An experiment is basically a patient on whom we observe the data (20 experiments on 20 patient resulting in 20 observation).